# How to link zip folders to newly created folder

Tags: perl

I am trying to copy data from a folder (named Zip) to a set of newly created folders.

Zip folder content is:

```
SO_90_X_L001_R1.fastq.gz
SO_100_X_L001_R1.fastq.gz
SO_101_X_L001_R1.fastq.gz
```

and I have created the following empty folders:

```
SO_90
SO_100
SO_101
```

Without giving keyboard input, is it possible to copy those zipped files to matching folders using Perl?

i tryed below script, than also i am not getting proper output.

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use File::Copy "cp";
open(my $F, "a.txt") or die("cant open a.txt\n");
  while(<$F>)
{
next unless /\S/;
mkdir $_ ;

}
close($F);
for my $file (<SO_/*.fastq.gz>){
  print $_;
  if( $file =~ m!SO_/(.*)_X_L001_R1.fastq.gz! ) {
     mkdir($_);              # comment this line if not necessary
     cp($file, "$1/") or  warn("Copy '$file, $1' failed\n"); 
  } else {
     warn("$file is not ending in '_X_L001_R1.fasta.gz'\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: I wasted my time by reading your question and having no clue what are you talking about, thus down voted it.

Comment: what u didnt understood???

Comment: `I am trying to copy the data to Zip folder to newly created folder` what is zip folder, is it plain folder which ends with `.gz` or `gz` archive? Data is going simultaneously **to** this zip folder and **to** "newly created one" (where does it come from, etc..)? Please go and study how to ask the question, http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes its a plain folders which ends with .gz , the newly created folders are empty, i want to copy those .gz files to newly created empty folders in same orders as folder created with out giving keyboard input now understood or still u have doughts?

Comment: Aditya, It is clear that you have some problems with English (80% of us are also not native English speakers). This time I will try to edit your question (I will add my interpretation in the end -- but you have to check it!!) Is this OK?

Comment: Aditiya, it is also problematic when the question changes (the previous answers make no sense...)

Comment: tyes sir u r edited question is correct. if possible give solution sir

Comment: help me out guys, still i am struggling to develop the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
perl -nle 'mkdir $_ if /\S/' a.txt
```

- `-l` to remove `\n` from folder names (otherwise folder name would be `SO_100\n`)
- `if /\S/` to skip possible empty-lines in the input file

---

(your question changed....) Update: If you need more complex processing, you may  build a script where you can include someting like:

```
open(my $F, "a.txt") or die("cant open a.txt\n");
while(<$F>){ 
  chomp;
  next unless /\S/;
  mkdir $_ ;
  #... do other things related with this folder...
}
close $F;
```

Comment: it will generate all the folders at a time??

Comment: If `a.txt` has 20 non-empty lines it will create 20 folders.

Comment: how to use this in perl script? somehow like this[system(-nle 'mkdir $_ if /\S/' a.txt)]??

Comment: sir if possible help me to above posted question.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing a new answer because we the question is in fact different.

We have several files like `ZIP/SO_100_X_L001_R1.fastq.gz` to copy to 
`SO_100/...`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use File::Copy "cp";

for my $file (<ZIP/*.fastq.gz>){
  print $_;
  if( $file =~ m!ZIP/(.*)_X_L001_R1.fastq.gz! ) {
     mkdir($1);              # comment this line if not necessary
     cp($file, "$1/") or  warn("Copy '$file, $1' failed\n"); 
  } else {
     warn("$file is not ending in '_X_L001_R1.fasta.gz'\n");
  }
}
```

Edit: I added some "warnings" in order to help with the debug

Comment: thank you so much sir, but its not showing any output. i have pasted mkdir code also , than also its not giving any output .

Comment: its creating new folders but, its not copying Zip folders to those folders.

Comment: I added some warnings to the code to help in debug. Check (1) is you folder named "ZIP"? (2) are your files  zip-files named `..._X_L001_R1.fastq.gz`?

Comment: this is my zip file name SO_90_X_L001_R1.fastq.gz, i want to copy this in to SO_90 folder

Comment: the file name is L00 onnly not LOO sir

Comment: Ok. In your script: close($F) must be outside the while cycle!

Comment: no changes sir, sir i am updating the code again, check once again

Comment: same output i am getting sir, kindly help me out

Comment: What is the current behavior? (1) is there any warnings? (2) could you run `find SO_ ` and post a part of it?

Comment: there is no warning sir, script is executing , syntax is ok, it is creating empty folders, but its not fetching data from zip files to corresponding folder

Comment: Have you evaluated the above script sir?@JJoao